# Remotely accessed Jupyter notebook has working slowly

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter, ambari

Remotely accessed Jupyter notebook from a linux machine has working too slowly and ambari server hosts shows the components are down ?

Working jupyter notebook can connected via putty from that machine using no-browser commnd.

Comment: Is your code running faster when you execute it in a shell? What does your code do? How much data are you trying to process? How many ressource do you assign to your spark application?